# How can you use powershell to document deleting logs?

Tags: powershell, admin, powershell-3.0, system-administration

I am new to powershell and I am just curious if when I use a script to delete logs is there a command that will gather how many logs were deleted and the amount of space that was cleared (memory wise) after deleting logs and put it into a text file? So I can just log in and view the document and know exactly how many logs were deleted and how much memory is now available after deleting those logs.

Comment: if you keep track of the files you are deleting & how big they are you could do this in the same script

Comment: Technically, no, there is no single command that will do this, but it can be done quite easily.  Are you hoping that someone will write this script for you, or are you just asking?  Typically, SO readers will help you with a problem with a script that you've written, but if you're wanting someone to write the whole script, you might get lucky.

Comment: I am asking for I am learning powershell on my own I would just like some guidance and pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that might get you going. It gets a list of .log files, deletes them and then prints some info on them (because the info has been already gathered).

```
$files = ls *.log
foreach ($file in $files) {
    del $file
    "Deleted: $($file.Name) Size: $($file.Length)" | set-content .\deletelog.txt
}
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you very much!

Comment: Be careful with the delete though, perhaps comment that out when you are testing your script (but a `#` in front of it). Also, marking my reply as an answer would also be great. ;)

Comment: I have this added to my script and will be testing it tomorrow. Thank you again.

Comment: This just occurred to me, you'll have to use `add-content` instead of  `set-content` if you want all lines to be appended to the deletelog.txt. Otherwise you'll only see the last deleted file in there.

Comment: I am running into an issue using the script you provided, I added my information and paths to your script when testing it and I cant seem to get the script to delete the files @n3wjack could you possibly give me some insight?

Comment: `#Sets age limit for log file retention (Two Weeks)
$LogAgeLimit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)

#Gets objects inside the path variable and runs it against age and size limits - Deletes all pertaining items in logging folder

$logtest = 'C:\Program Files\somefile\somefile2\logtest\'

$files = ls *.log
foreach ($_ in $files) {
    if (!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.creationdate -lt $AgeLimit -or $_.length -gt 1mb) {
    del $file
    "Deleted: $($file.Name) Size: $($file.Length)" | add-content C:\Scripts\output\deletelog.txt
 }
}`

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. Sorry if this is crazy to look at like I said I am new to powershell working on getting the feel and making this script work for my project.

Comment: don't use $_ but your own variable if you are setting up the foreach yourself as in `foreach ($file in $files)` . Maybe that's it. Otherwise I guess the if condition isn't true, which you can verify by having the script print out the test variables so you can manually verify if that is correct.